# Как получить ответ скрипта на страницу сайта?

Tags: node.js

Имеется тестовое приложение написанное на Node.JS

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    getClick();
});

app.listen(3000);
function getClick() {
    console.log('Клик получен');
}
```

Как можно понять, оно ловит клик с сайта и оповещает об этом в консоли.
Клик ловится вот таким образом

```
  $('#button').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/'
        });
    });
```

Вопрос в следующем. Каким образом отправлять ответ о получении клика не в консоль а обратно на страницу, с которой был отправлен клик?

Comment: Я не понимаю людей, которые минусуют вопрос. Если он вам кажется идиотским, может вы ответите? Что не так с вами?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19696240/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    req.json({handled: true});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { console.log(data) }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

На стороне сервера:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    getClick(res);
});

function getClick(res) {
    res.send('Клик получен');
}
```

На клиенте:

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // <- "Клик получен"
        }
    });
});
```